# My php.ini file is missing

Tags: php

I just installed php on my computer and I can't seem to find my `php.ini` file.. I tried running phpinfo and searching for the answer there but was out of luck.

[image]

I also searched it through the windows explorer search bar but it cannot be found. Where can I get that `php.ini` file?

Comment: Maybe you forgot to place it in.

Comment: How did you install PHP?

Comment: I downloaded it from here http://windows.php.net/download, extracted the zip folder and placed it on my C: drive

Comment: it will be inside PHP folder

Comment: well, i searched the whole C: drive and there were no results. I have though, php.ini-development and php.ini-production

Comment: then copy one of that to php.ini. Those are samples.